# filter using exact with a many_to_many field django model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

I have this definitions into `models.py`:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='ProdGroup')

class ProdGroup(models.Model):
    groups= models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_prd_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, default='', max_length=12)
```

I want to check if I already have a Group with the same products in the database, *not more, not less*. (and also check if the prd_main is the same).

I don't know if it's a problem with the `through` option but this doesn't work:

```
group = Group.objects.all()[0] # an instance already in the db
Group.objects.filter(products__exact=group.products)
<QuerySet []>
```

***Edit:*** I also try with:

```
Group.objects.filter(products__in=group.products.all()) # it works, but it returns also groups that partialy have the products in group
Group.objects.filter(products__exact=group.products.all()) #ERORR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

it's there a way, given an object `group` to check of its already in the db?, it's there a way to obtain all the `products` and filter all the Groups with the same unique set of `products`?

Comment: What is `PSG` and where does it come from?

Comment: @cezar, it was `Group` sorry

Answer (score 0):

So you are fetching one entry with this line:

```
group = Group.objects.all()[0]
```

Now if you want to get the products for `group` you have to do it like this:

```
group.products.all()
```

If you do only:

```
group.products
```

you'll get only an instance of `ManyRelatedManager`.

Try to change the filter query:

```
Group.objects.filter(products__exact=group.products.all())
```

It should do the job.

EDIT:

You can further enhance the query and exclude the group that serves as searching reference:

```
Group.objects.filter(products__exact=group.products.all()).exclude(id=group.id)
```

UPDATE:

Usually when I query many2many relations, I use list of ids. In this case it could be done like this:

```
group = Group.objects.all()[0]
# or maybe better
group = Group.objects.all().first()
product_ids = list(group.products.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
Group.objects.filter(products__exact=product_ids)
```

Although I'm not sure if this is going to change anything.

Comment: I reimplemented the model from scratch and partly it worked, now it gives me an error `more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression`, im looking on how to fix that

Comment: I think the problem its with `__exact` usage and the fact that `group.products.all()` has many results ..

Comment: What happens then if you leave out `exact` and make the query like this: `Group.objects.filter(products=group.products.all())`?

Comment: Also you can try to get the ids for the products and query against them. See the updated answer.