# Getting all objects with equal M2M fields

Tags: django, m2m

I am looking for a way to filter for all objects of the same type that have the same querysets for a M2M field.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='comment_user')    
    content = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True)

    private_to = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, related_name='private_to')
```

Given a comment object, I want to retrieve all other comments who have an equal M2M field (i.e. if the private_to field returns User 1 and User 2 for the comment, it will find all the other comments that contain exactly both of those users in the private_to field.)

Is there a concise, built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47555854/filter-using-exact-with-a-many-to-many-field-django-model?noredirect=1&lq=1):

```
comment = Comment.objects.all()[0] # Or the comment you want to filter by.

private_to_ids = list(comment.private_to.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
comments = Comment.objects.filter(private_to__exact=private_to_ids)
```

Comment: Is there a way to additionally get all the unique combinations of private_to?

Comment: You mean all the existing (currently assigned) combinations of the private_to m2m? You could get all the Comments and for each append comment.private_to.all().values_list('id', flat=True) to an array if the set is not already included in it